# mysql query with case using result as a variable

Tags: mysql, variables, case, case-when

I need a query like following that doen not work:

```
SELECT *, 
 CASE 
  WHEN x_sutun1 = '1' OR x_sutun2 >= CURRENT_DATE() THEN 0 
  WHEN x_sutun1 < 1 AND x_sutun2 < CURRENT_DATE() THEN 1 
 END as mecit
FROM tablo1
LEFT JOIN tablo2 ON x_sutun0 = y_sutun0
LEFT JOIN tablo3 ON x_sutun0 = z_sutun0
WHERE x_sutun3 + mecit < 4
```

How can I use 'mecit' as a variable (without stored procedure if possible).

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your query in an outer query like this:

```
select * from
(
SELECT 
 *
 , CASE 
  WHEN x_sutun1 = '1' OR x_sutun2 >= CURRENT_DATE() THEN 0 
  WHEN x_sutun1 < 1 AND x_sutun2 < CURRENT_DATE() THEN 1 
 END as mecit
FROM tablo1
) m
LEFT JOIN tablo2 ON x_sutun0 = y_sutun0
LEFT JOIN tablo3 ON x_sutun0 = z_sutun0
WHERE x_sutun3 + m.mecit < 4
```

The reason for this is that the alias you use is not visible until the SELECT has been resolved, which is the last (or almost) last part of the query to be looked at by the engine.

Note: you'll need to qualify column names if you have name collisions over the tables you are using.

Answer (score 1):

As documented under [Problems with Column Aliases](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/problems-with-alias.html):

> An alias can be used in a query select list to give a column a different name. You can use the alias in `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`, or `HAVING` clauses to refer to the column:
>
> ```
> [ deletia ]
> ```
>
> Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a `WHERE` clause. This restriction is imposed because when the `WHERE` clause is evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined.

Therefore you cannot reference `mecit` by alias in the `WHERE` clause.  Whilst you could move the filter to a `HAVING` clause (or an outer query), that's generally not very efficient (as records cannot be filtered until all results have been computed and returned): you're better off just repeating the expression in the `WHERE` clause directly (more verbose, but more performant):

```
SELECT *, 
 CASE 
  WHEN x_sutun1 = '1' OR x_sutun2 >= CURRENT_DATE() THEN 0 
  WHEN x_sutun1 <  1 AND x_sutun2 <  CURRENT_DATE() THEN 1 
 END as mecit
FROM tablo1
LEFT JOIN tablo2 ON x_sutun0 = y_sutun0
LEFT JOIN tablo3 ON x_sutun0 = z_sutun0
WHERE x_sutun3 + CASE 
  WHEN x_sutun1 = '1' OR x_sutun2 >= CURRENT_DATE() THEN 0 
  WHEN x_sutun1 <  1 AND x_sutun2 <  CURRENT_DATE() THEN 1 
 END < 4
```